# Angular ngOptions Dropdown 'Undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Firstly:

```js
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $ionicPlatform) {
 // This disables the user from being able to go back to the previous view
 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
 }, 100);
 
 console.log("Getting Profile");
 var temp = window.localStorage.getItem("UserProfile");
 var profile = JSON.parse(temp);
 var topicList = [];
 
 for (var i = 0; i < profile.UserTopics.length; i++) {
  var topicName = profile.UserTopics[i].topicName;
  topicList.push(topicName);
 }
 $scope.topics = topicList;
```

There is my code. I am putting a list of topics into my dropdown menu called `topics`. When I put `topicList` into the dropdown, I get several `undefined`. But when I `console.log (topicList)` the data is correct. How come when I put it in my html dropdown, the data is `undefined`?

Comment: try change  `$scope.topics` to `$scope.topics = [] ` then use `$scope.topics = topicList;`

Comment: It is still undefined. I guess it might help if i show the code of what $scope.topics is:

`<select ng-model="selectTopic" ng-change="changedValue(selectSubject)" data-ng-options="option.topics for option in topics">
     <option value="" disabled>Select a Topic</option>
    </select>`

It is a html dropdown menu. I am trying to populate it with that array.

Comment: why use temp array? you can use `$scope.topics.push(topicName);` directly.

Comment: I did that, and it is still undefined. But does make sense, no need for a temp array.

Comment: try this `ng-options="option as option for option in topics">`

Comment: That did it!? How come? Can you please explain? That was killing me! Cant up vote enough.

Comment: the `topics` is array and don't have key/value object. you use in ng-options   key object that it has not it.